# React Firestore Useeffect error type error "undefined indexOf" when accessing user collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

Getting a particular error on first render of useeffect that i am not sure how to get around. I believe it has to do with the async nature of the function but not sure. Project is a Reactjs, Firebase, Firestore Todo app that updates data based on user signed in.

````
useEffect( () => {
    const getData = async () => {
        
        const  uid = await user.uid; //from context of user object
    console.log(uid);
    
        const q = await query(collection(db,'userData', uid, 'todos'));

        const  unsubscribe =   onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
            let todosArr = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              todosArr.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
            });
            setTodos(todosArr)
          });
          return () => unsubscribe();
    }
       getData();

    
   
       
      
    
    }, [user.uid]);
```




This is the Error in the console :

    path.ts:230 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
    at ResourcePath.fromString (path.ts:230:1)
    at collection (reference.ts:418:1)
    at getData (TodoPage.js:63:1)
fromString @ path.ts:230
collection @ reference.ts:418
getData @ TodoPage.js:63
await in getData (async)
(anonymous) @ TodoPage.js:73


I tried making the uid data a state outside of the useeffect but still not working. Wondering how i can fix this error from within the useeffect. Thanks for your help!
````

Comment: Please show full error message

Comment: It would also help if you showed which line of code causes the error.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
    at ResourcePath.fromString (path.ts:230:1)
    at collection (reference.ts:418:1)
    at getData (TodoPage.js:63:1)

Comment: the line that caused is the const q

Comment: That doesn't look like a reference to your code.  Which line of *your* code causes the error?  Please edit the question to add new data (don't add it in a comment).

Comment: ive edited the post now. please let me know if the issue is clearer now, I really appreciate any help you can give with this!